# Eclipse JDT: How to get java package name of a non-existing IFolder

Tags: eclipse-rcp, eclipse-jdt

Given an IFolder instsance fd (fd may or may not exist), how to get the java package name if fd represents a java package? Currently I coded in this way

```
IJavaProject jp = JavaCore.create(fd.getProject());
IPackageFragment pf = jp.findPackageFragment(f.getFullPath());
String pname = pf.getElementName();
```

The code failed when fd does not exist (for example it was just deleted and the deletion was caught in IResourceDelta of an IResourceChangeListener), as IJavaProject#findPackageFragment(IPath) returns null for non-existing item. How to get the package name for a non-existing IFolder? Thanks

Comment: Maybe I'm thinking of this backwards, or maybe you are, but if it doesn't exist yet, wouldn't its name be whatever you wanted appended to its parent IFolder's package name?

Comment: The failed case is fd was just deleted. It was accessed by using IResourceDelta in a ResourceChangeListener. So at the moment Project was just updated and fd did not exist. But I still need to get its package name. Any suggestion? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Does the inexistent IFolder still have a useful parent chain? If so, you may want to find the parent that corresponds to a package fragment root of the current project.

```
IContainer parent = fd.getParent();
while (parent != null) {
    if (JavaCore.create(parent) instanceof IPackageFragmentRoot)
        // success: parent is a source folder
    else
        parent = parent.getParent();
}
```

Then take the relative path from the package fragment root to the folder as the package name.

```
IPath myPath = fd.getFullPath();
IPath parentPath = parent.getFullPath();
IPath packagePath = myPath.makeRelativeTo(parentPath);
```

PS: per JLS a package is only observable if a compilation unit in the package is observable. Ergo an inexistent folder can never represent a package (but I admit this is picking on words).

Comment: This bug leads to a much bigger issue in the project. I need to work on that first. Your code snippet and comments helped me to figure out the issue. Thank you very much